# jQuery while loop posting crashed browser

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

my jQuery code i want while loop and posting data span id , i get span data but post crashed.

```
    while (ilkDeger < toplamDeger) {    
            var yukle ="yukle"+ilkDeger ;   
            var tekalan = '&'+$("#yukle"+ilkDeger+" :input").serialize();
            var veriler = data;
            //alert(ilkveri+tekalan);

          $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: veriler,

                  success: function(sonuc){

                  //Gelen postu süzgeçle
                    var $response=$(sonuc);
                    var sonuc = $response.find('#cevap').val();
                    var yanit = $response.find('#yanit').text();

                    var baslangic = $response.find('#baslangic').val();
                    var limit = $response.find('#limit').val();
                    var servis = $response.find('#servis').val();

                    //Proggress Bar kodları                 
                    var prodeger=ilkDeger+1;

                    if(prodeger < <?=$top;?>) {
                        var olcu=(prodeger/<?=$top;?>*100);
                        $('.progress-bar').css('width', olcu+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', olcu).html(olcu+'%'); 

                    }else{

                        $('.progress-bar').css('width', 100 + '%').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('Tamamlandı.').attr('aria-valuenow', '100');



                        $('#progress-bar').css('width', 100 + '%').addClass('progress-bar-success');
                        }


                       if (sonuc == "1"){ 
                            $('#yukle'+ilkDeger).html('<b><font color=green>BAŞARILI : </font>'+yanit+'</b><hr>');                      
                            console.log(" Ürün Aktarıldı ");

                            ilkDeger++; 
                        }
                        else if (sonuc=="0"){
                            $('#yukle'+ilkDeger).html('<b><font color=red>HATA : </font>'+yanit+'</b><hr>');
                            //$('#yukle'+ilkDeger).html('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>'+yanit+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button></div>');

                            console.log(yanit);
                            ilkDeger++;

                            } else {
                            $('#yukle'+ilkDeger).html('<b><font color=red>HATA : </font>Geçersiz işlem</b><hr>');

                            console.log(yanit);
                            ilkDeger++;
                            } 


                    }  

                    }    ));
               }
```

I add async:false mozilla working,chrome crashed , how i can fixed i want part part posting data.I can send data and proccess is not view crash browser

```
<span id=yukle0></span>
<span id=yukle1></span>
<span id=yukle2></span>
<span id=yukle3></span>
```

$.ajax( { } ) not working crash browser

Comment: Don't do that.  You should make your code properly asynchronous.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. The callback function won't be executed until after you get out of the loop. But you can't get out of the loop until the callback function increments the variable. Do you see the problem with this?

Comment: i little speak english you . Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how ajax works: Your ajax call gets executed and then the code continues.

Your variable gets incremented in the `success` function of the ajax call so when that call has finished. However, your loop keeps looping until that happens (multiple times...) so your browser will crash as it keeps generating new ajax calls.

Apart from that you probably don't need to make ajax calls in a loop, especially if you just increase a counter in that loop. You can easily do that in php using just one ajax call.

Comment: Thaks for commet, i posting big data i want use jQuery , server limited max_input_vars. Can you give an example? –

Comment: @Agt Just put `ilkDeger++;` after the ajax call.

Comment: thanks simultaneously loading data, success not work ilkDeger an increasing number @jeroen